# Rails test fails with fixture but passes with direct object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I have a test:

```
test 'gift should not be saved with a non-numeric price' do
  @gift = gifts(:gift_without_numeric_price)
  assert_not @gift.save, 'gift was saved with non-numeric name'
end
```

It uses this fixture:

```
gift_without_numeric_price:
  name: "pinecones"
  description: "these pinecones smell really good"
  estimated_price: "object"
  link: "www.google.com"
```

My `Gift` model looks like this:

```
validates :estimated_price,
        presence: true,
        numericality: true
```

So I was expecting the test to pass since 'object' is not numeric, causing the `@gift.save` to return false and causing the `assert_not` to ultimately return true. However, the test fails for some reason. When I use the the direct way of creating a gift object, the test looks like this and the test passes:

```
test 'gift should not be saved with a non-numeric price' do
  @gift = Gift.new(name: 'aa', description: 'description', link: 'www.google.com', estimated_price: 'object')
  assert_not @gift.save, 'gift was saved with non-numeric name'
end
```

What am I doing wrong with the fixture?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and change your validation:

```
validates :estimated_price, presence: true,numericality: { only_integer: true }
```

Comment: I don't want the price to be an integer though..it should be a float

Comment: you could write your custom validation that checks your condition and pass it to validates.